# Separar String de Coordenadas em Array com Lat Long separados?

Tags: php

Estou precisando separar uma string de coordenadas `lat`/`long` em `PHP` que estão no formato abaixo em um array separando a latitude da longitude:

> `[-23.61025,-46.5871],[-23.61006,-46.58824],[-23.61005,-46.58831],[-23.60999,-46.5886],[-23.60988,-46.58906],[-23.60969,-46.58946],[-23.60961,-46.5896],[-23.60944,-46.58979],[-23.60917,-46.59014]`

Já tentei com Regex, mas não obtive o resultado esperado.

Preciso fazer com o que eles estejam em um registro do `array` separado, para pode realizar a leitura e comparação separada de cada um destes `lat`/`long`.

Comment: então é um texto isso tudo?

Comment: Sim, é uma string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tenta o seguinte:

```php
<?php
//
$re = '/\[.*?\]/m';
$str = '[-23.61025,-46.5871],[-23.61006,-46.58824],[-23.61005,-46.58831],[-23.60999,-46.5886],[-23.60988,-46.58906],[-23.60969,-46.58946],[-23.60961,-46.5896],[-23.60944,-46.58979],[-23.60917,-46.59014]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$_arr = [];

foreach ($matches as $value){

    $arr = explode(",",$value[0]);

    $lat = str_replace("[","", $arr[0]);

    $long = str_replace("]","", $arr[1]);

    array_push($_arr, ["lat" => $lat, "long" => $long]);
}

var_dump($_arr);

?>
```

**Saída:**

```js
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(9) "-23.61025"
    ["long"]=>
    string(8) "-46.5871"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(9) "-23.61006"
    ["long"]=>
    string(9) "-46.58824"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(9) "-23.61005"
    ["long"]=>
    string(9) "-46.58831"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(9) "-23.60999"
    ["long"]=>
    string(8) "-46.5886"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(9) "-23.60988"
    ["long"]=>
    string(9) "-46.58906"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(9) "-23.60969"
    ["long"]=>
    string(9) "-46.58946"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(9) "-23.60961"
    ["long"]=>
    string(8) "-46.5896"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(9) "-23.60944"
    ["long"]=>
    string(9) "-46.58979"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    string(9) "-23.60917"
    ["long"]=>
    string(9) "-46.59014"
  }
}
```

**Demonstração:**
https://paiza.io/projects/ctetBoD2GpgFT8zEZ4n2Kg?language=php

**REFERÊNCIA:**

1. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php
2. https://regex101.com

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente o que eu precisava. Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive a ideia da seguinte forma, quebrar esse texto no ponto `],[` onde posso constatar a divisão dessas coordenadas e com `array_map` montar as coordenadas em um novo `array` *associativo* da seguinte forma:

***Código:***

```
$texto = '[-23.61025,-46.5871],[-23.61006,-46.58824],[-23.61005,-46.58831],
          [-23.60999,-46.5886],[-23.60988,-46.58906],[-23.60969,-46.58946],
          [-23.60961,-46.5896],[-23.60944,-46.58979],[-23.60917,-46.59014]';

function get_coordinates($texto) {
    $parte = explode('],[', $texto);
    return array_map(
        function($item) { 
            list($lat, $long) = explode(',', substr(str_replace(']','',$item));
            return ['lat' => $lat, 'long' => $long];
        }, $parte
    );
}

print_r(get_coordinates($texto));
```

***Saída:***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lat] => -23.61025
            [long] => -46.5871
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 23.61006
            [long] => -46.58824
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 23.61005
            [long] => -46.58831
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 23.60999
            [long] => -46.5886
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 23.60988
            [long] => -46.58906
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 23.60969
            [long] => -46.58946
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 23.60961
            [long] => -46.5896
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 23.60944
            [long] => -46.58979
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 23.60917
            [long] => -46.59014
        )

)
```

Com esses dados em `array` você pode acessar as posições e visualizar as informações como precisar